# "Securing" images in WordPress

Tags: plugin-recommendation, media

I'm generally against the practice of making images difficult to download on websites.

However, we have a number of photographic contributors who grant us exclusive free access to their images.

Not long back I had an instance of a website using a lot of our information including photographs.

What steps can I take to secure our images? I appreciate that it will never be bullet-proof, but I'd like to make it at least mildly difficult.

The likes of a watermark would probably be ideal, but I know very little about the subject.

**EDIT**: It has just occurred to me, having watched a Watermarking plugin demonstration video, that I need my users to be able to view the image perfectly, but for it to be downloaded with a watermark (i.e. if they right click > save as). Obviously this makes things much more complicated and I realise that the images will be susceptible to screenshotting and `wget`, but at least I'll make it somewhat difficult for some would-be image thieves.

Do any such plugins exist, or are there any built-in WordPress functions which might help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Watermarking images isn't something unique to WordPress ... this question feels a bit off topic to me. Do you want me to migrate it to Stack Overflow so you can get some deeper answers?

Comment: I agree to an extent EAMann, but I guess I was hoping that there might be a plugin to help me out! I'll amend my question on here to include the appropriate tag.

Comment: Untested, but I've recently came across this gist done by @viper007bond https://gist.github.com/1187563

Answer (score 1):

A [search of the plugin repo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/watermark) reveals plenty of options. I'd probably start with [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/transparent-image-watermark-plugin/).

Comment: You've just made me realise I have slightly more complicated requirements - I want users to be able to view the image unmolested! Obviously this means it'll be susceptible to being screenshotted but I can live with that as it would take ages to steal a number of images. I'll update my original post.